# GET request with parameters when using vue-resource in vue js

Tags: parameters, vue.js

Hello i am trying to fetch details of task when clicked on task name the get api should take task name as parameter and return the task details i am unable to pass the parameter in my api

Answer (score 0):

This solution could help you which is of vue-resource :

```
fetchdata() {
        this.$http.get('data.json') //this data.json in URL provided to fetch from firebase
        .then(response => {
           return response.json(); //returns json from domainURL
        })
        .then(data => {
            const resultArray = []; //defined a resultarray to store the data
            for (let key in data){
                     resultArray.push(data[key]); //pushed data into resultarray             
            }
            this.users = resultArray; 
        });
    },
```

Comment: can you please add comments in the above answer

Comment: If you need full project code of my vue-resource example, here it is - https://github.com/Meetzaveri/Vue.js-with-Vue-resource-and-firebase

Comment: Vue-resource is removed from vue 2.0?

Comment: yes dude it was removed and also it didn't displayed from vue 2.0 documentation and yet many are using. But I am using axios API for reliable support

Comment: If you want axios example , I have also made project on it also ! here's the link - https://github.com/Meetzaveri/Vue.js-with-Axios-and-firebase